# Should onLayout be overridden if there are no views inside

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-viewgroup

I have created a custom control which extends `ViewGroup`. Eventually, the implementation of the control is using only a canvas to draw some shapes on, without adding any `View`s.

Should `onLayout` be still overridden in that scenario with some sort of general implementation, or should I leave it an empty method?

Comment: If you don't intend to have any children, why use a ViewGroup? Might be easier to just extend View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should onLayout be still overridden in that scenario

If you are extending `ViewGroup` then yes, you have to implement `onLayout()` even if it does nothing as it's abstract method. Alternatively extend i.e. `FrameLayout` instead of `ViewGroup`.

> How would a general implementation be?

If you got no children to layout just keep empty method body.

**EDIT**

> Yeah I meant if I should have some sort of a general implementation or just leave it empty

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> void onLayout ()
>
> Called from layout when this view should assign a
>   size and position to each of its children. Derived classes **with
>   children** should override this method and call layout on each of their
>   children.

There's no point for implementation if there's no use for it. There's no universal implementation that's why this method is `abstract` in `ViewGroup`. You got no childer then you not need to layout anything. Yet you need the
(empty) method due to extending abstract class.

Comment: Yeah I meant if I should have some sort of a general implementation or just leave it empty